# Embedded records in ember-data 1.0 beta

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My records are not flat. They have this structure:

```
{
    'type' : 'node',
    'properties' : {
        'name' : 'sfddsadfsd',
        'xxx'  : 'sadfdsf',
    },
    'outputs' : {
        'fghdf' : 'sadfdsf',
        'xxxx'  : 'sdfsd',
    }
}
```

You get the idea. Those fields (`properties` and `outputs`) do not refer to *sideloaded* records; instead, they are part of my record (in my CouchDb database). I did this (before learning that this is a sin by ember-data standards) because it is a handy way of organizing lots of properties in a document - the term that CouchDb uses for records. This name also suggest why you want to have structure in your record: because a document can get quite big, and thus you need some organizing structure to make your life easier (or so I thought, before bumping into ember-data).

I was happily modelling these records using embedded properties with the previous version of ember-data. Now, it seems that ember-data has [dropped support](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#embedded-records) for embedded records. There is a suggestion of implementing `extractSingle` and do some funky stuff with `mapProperty('id');`

Well: since they are part of my record, the embedded properties/outputs **have no record id**. There is simply no concept of *property* or *output* outside the *node*. They are not independent data with IDs: they are just part of the *node*.

Previously I had the following model definition:

```
SettingsApp.NodeProperties = DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr('string'),
});

DS.RESTAdapter.map('SettingsApp.NodeProperties', {
    name : {key: 'name'},
});

SettingsApp.Node = DS.Model.extend(SettingsApp.NodeMixin, {
    properties : DS.belongsTo('nodeProperties')
});

DS.RESTAdapter.map('SettingsApp.Node', {
    nodeType:   {key: 'type'},
    outputs:    {embedded: 'always'},
    properties: {embedded: 'always'}
});
```

(`outputs` is part of the  `NodeMixin`)

What are my options of modelling this with ember-data 1.0 beta? I have no idea what to do with these models, and I have around a dozen of them. It was hard enough to shove my record structure into ember-data, and now ... *puff*, effort gone, it just does not work anymore.

Comment: As mentioned on the TRANSITION.md : `Explicit support for embedded records is gone for now.` (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#embedded-records)
For now i don't think you can handle embedded records without id's. So yes this is a kind of regression compare to 0.13. Take a look to this discuss : http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-1-0beta-embedded-records/2359/14

Comment: Thanks. That does not seem very encouraging :( Do you know if I can continue with ember-data 0.13 and the latest version of ember? For what I read, ember-data 1.0 beta is still buggy and probably subject to changes. I would prefer to wait for ember-data 1.0 before going through this huge effort.

Comment: Sure you can. I got the same issue (MongoDB database) and I really consider staying in 0.13 until embedded records are properly handled by ember-data. The thing is, there is no information from the core team about this feature. We do not even know if this feature will be part of ember data 1.0

Comment: Another question: latest version of ember-data 0.13 is `v0.13-221-gef11bff`, from 2013-08-27 (see [here] (http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/daily/20130827/ember-data.js), all versions [here](http://builds.emberjs.com/)) From then on, I only see releases for ember-data 1.0. Do you know if there will be further releases for ember-data 0.13?

Comment: I don't know... I guess the core team want to focus on the version 1.0

Comment: @gonvaled what is the story here? Have you find any solution with v1.0. Documentation looks like it encourages to override serializer?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to just use `properties` and `outputs` as raw JSON data you can declare them as non-typed `DS.attr` and they will be passed through as is.

```
SettingsApp.Node = DS.Model.extend(SettingsApp.NodeMixin, {
    properties : DS.attr(),
    outputs : DS.attr()
});
```